# Can't find integral of $ \int \frac{1}{x^2+2ax+b^2} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have been struggling for the past 2 hours to solve the following integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2+2ax+b^2} dx
$$
I have tested some replacements for x, like $$u = \frac{ab + x}{ab}$$ and $$u = \frac{a + x}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}$$
, but nothing seems to work.
The solution according to Wolfram is the following:
$$
\frac{\arctan(\frac{a + x}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}})}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}
$$
I have also tried to go backwards from this solution. Do you have any suggestions for replacing x. Should I use some other method to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Complete the square in the denominator, then do a change of variables (or two).

Comment: $$\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+2ax+b^2}dx=\int\dfrac{1}{(x+a)^2+(b^2-a^2)}dx=\dfrac{1}{b^2-a^2}\int\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{x+a}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)^2+1}dx$$ Put $\dfrac{x+a}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}=y$ and you get your integral equal to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\int\frac{1}{y^2+1}dy$$

Comment: @Piquito I think that people probably learn more by working out at least some of a problem by themselves, but I do think it's very nice of you to provide a full solution.

Comment: @Piquito: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: I know what you say, dear friend.

Comment: @A-Level Student: Thanks for your comment, dear friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**
Complete the square in the denominator, and then using a suitable substitution make use of the formula
$$\int\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan{\frac{x}{a}}+C$$

In general, whenever you have an integral of the form
$$\int\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$$  often the easiest and quickest way to approach it is to complete the square in the denominator, make a suitable substitution and then make use of the standard integral above, or if necessary use the standard integral
$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx=-\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{x}{a}+C$$

---

I hope that helps. If you need any more help please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out square completion was the knowledge I was missing. Once I did it, the problem solved itself.

Comment: @User9123 My pleasure, I'm glad I could help you! Actually, I just realized my answer wasn't quite correct. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a standard formula:

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 + k^2}dx = \frac{1}{k} \arctan(\frac{x}{k}) + C $$

Proof:

In the above integral, substitute $ x = k \tan u \Rightarrow u = \arctan (\frac{x}{k}) $

Differentiating, we get $ dx = k\sec^2 u \ du $. The integral becomes:

$$  k\int \frac{\sec^2u \ du}{k^2 \tan^2 u + k^2}dx $$

Factoring out the k, taking it out of the integral and simplifying:

$$ \frac{1}{k} \int \frac{\sec^2 u}{1 + \tan^2 u}  du $$

Using $1 + \tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$, This simplifies to $\frac{1}{k}\int du = \frac{u}{k} + C$

Recall that $u = \arctan(\frac{x}{k})$, and we get the formula that was given above.

Also note that if $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$, then $\int f(ax + b) dx = \frac{1}{a}F(ax +b) + C$

---

Now, for your problem, we first complete the square: Since $ (x+a)^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$, we add $b^2$ and subtract $a^2$. $b^2 - a^2 $ is a constant, so it fulfills the role of $k^2$ in our previous formula. Thus $k = \sqrt{b^2 - a^2}$

SO $x^2 + 2ax + b^2 = (x+a)^2 + (\sqrt{b^2 - a^2})^2$

Substitute this in the integral formula at the top and you get the answer

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 2ax + b^2}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}} \arctan(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{b^2 - a^2}}) + C $$

Answer (score 0):

$\int \frac{1}{x^2+2ax+b^2} dx$ = $\int \frac{1}{(x+a)^2+b^2-a^2} dx$

It becomes $\int \frac{1}{(x+a)^2+c^2} dx$  = $c^2$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{(x+a)^2}{c^2}+1} dx$

Now take y = (x+a)/c

So it becomes $\frac{1}{c^2}\int\frac{1}{y^2+1}$
now its in tan inverse form

Note: I have considered $b^2 - a^2$ positive. If it is negative you have to factorize it and use log form.